# Using truncate tables, no result

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, truncate

I'm trying to truncate the table named 'comments' Yet every time I run the script nothing happens. What is wrong with my syntax?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if (!$con)
mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE 'comments'");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes, try changing it to:

```
$result = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `comments`");
if ( !$result ) print(mysql_error());
```

This will also tell you what goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

you seem to select the database "dbname" only if the connection to the mysql server failed ( $con == FALSE ).

you probably need to change your if condition to:

```
    if ( $con )
        mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
```